# how do i make a snackbar respond onPress?

Tags: react-native

Im having problem with my `<SnackBar>`.

**It is not responding when i click on it.**

Is there a way i can improve this code to work as i have tried many sources from the internet without avail?

```js
<Snackbar
  visible={snack.visible}
  onDismiss={() =>
    setSnack({
      ...snack,
      visible: false,
      click: false,
    })
  }
  action={{
    label: <AntDesign name="close" size={24} color="black" />,
    onPress: () => {
      setSnack({
        ...snack,
        visible: false,
        click: false,
      });
    },
  }}
  style={{
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    padding: 30,
    marginLeft: 0,
  }}>
  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setSnack({...snack, click: true})}>
      {snack.click === true ? (
        <Text>{snack.message}</Text>
      ) : (
        <Text>Touch me to see changes</Text>
      )}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</Snackbar>
```

and i dave set my states properly like this:

```js
const [snack, setSnack] = useState({
  visible: false,
  message: 'You clicked me',
  click: false,
});
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Snackbar
        visible={snack.visible}
        duration={1000000}
        onDismiss={() =>
          setSnack({
            ...snack,
            visible: false,
            click: false,
          })
        }
        action={{
          label: <AntDesign name="close" size={24} color="black" />,
          onPress: () => {
            setSnack({
              ...snack,
              visible: false,
              click: false,
            });
          },
        }}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          padding: 0
        }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => setSnack({ ...snack, click: true })}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 30 }}>
            {snack.click === true ? (
              <Text>{snack.message}</Text>
            ) : (
              <Text>Touch me to see changes</Text>
            )}
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Snackbar>
```

I ran the above code on snack.expo.io. It's working. There's padding around the snack (a default from react-native-paper), where the onPress cannot be called as well as the section that has the icon to dismiss the snack. Rest of the area calls the onPress. The problem was that the onPress was only restricted to the text area. But rearranging the view with style: `flex: 1` fills the remaining space now.